# Erro na paginação com custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, funções, paginação

Eu tenho dois Custom post type criado, um para filmes e outro para series, eu tenho um loop que mostra os dois na index, só que quando eu uso a paginação, não funciona.

Ex.: 
Aperto para ir para a /page/2
Só que eu recebo um erro 404, como se não existisse a pagina 2.

Procurando no github e nos fóruns da SO eu encontrei uma possível solução, quando eu adiciono essa função na functions.php e erro some, só que quando eu vou para a pagina 2, aparece o mesmo post na /page/2

```
add_filter( 'request' , 'pagination_request_filter' );

function pagination_request_filter( $query ) {

    // https://wpquestions.com/Trouble_with_custom_post_type_pagination/937

    if ( empty( $query['preview'] ) && empty( $query['feed'] ) ) {
        $my_post_type = $query['post_type'];
        if ( empty( $my_post_type ) ) {
            $query['post_type'] = 'any';
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Meu loop que eu estou utilizando na index e esse, não estou usando nenhum plugin para paginação, tentei usar o wp-pagenavi mas sem sucesso.

vou deixa o código completo:

```
<ol id="posts" class="posts">
<?php $args = array('post_type'=>array('filmes', 'series')); query_posts($args); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php   if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
$imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'home');
$imgsrc = $imgsrc[0];
} elseif ($postimages = get_children("post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=0")) {
foreach($postimages as $postimage) {
$imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($postimage->ID, 'home');
$imgsrc = $imgsrc[0];
}
} elseif (preg_match('/
<img [^>]*src=["|\']([^"|\']+)/i', get_the_content(), $match) != FALSE) {
$imgsrc = $match[1];
} else {
$imgsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/no-imagen.png';
} ?>
<li class="post_container" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="post post_full">
<div class="post_avatar post-avatar--sticky">
<div class="post_avatar_wrapper">
<?php $id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
if (is_user_online($id) ) {
echo '<span class="tag-status tag-status-online"></span>';
} else {
echo '<span class="tag-status tag-status-offline"></span>';
}
?>
<a class="post_avatar_link">
<div class="post_avatar_image"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '64' ); ?></div>
</a>

<div class="post_avatar_desc">
<div class="tooltipped tooltipped-n tooltipped-multiline" aria-label="<?php the_author_meta('description'); ?>" style="position: relative;">
<i class="far fa-info-circle"></i>
</div>
<span class="tooltipped tooltipped-n qpost-cont" aria-label="Autor de <?php the_author_posts() ?> postagens"><?php the_author_posts() ?></span>
<span class="qpost-desc">Postagens</span>
<em class="userBanner <?php echo get_author_role(); ?>">
<span class="before <?php echo get_author_role(); ?>"></span>
<strong class="tooltipped tooltipped-n befafter" aria-label="<?php echo get_author_role(); ?>"><?php echo get_author_role(); ?></strong>
<span class="after <?php echo get_author_role(); ?>"></span>
</em>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="post_wrapper">
<div class="post_header">
<div class="post_info">
<div class="post_info_fence">
<a class="post_info_link"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
<span class="reblog_source">
<i class="fas fa-badge-check" style="color: #4FC3F7;"></i>
<a class="post_info_link tooltipped tooltipped-n" aria-label="Atualizado há <?php echo meks_time_ago(); ?> - <?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?>">Adicionado há <?php echo meks_time_ago(); ?></a>
</span>
</div>
<div class="post_action_wrapper"><?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_audio_video')) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="post_content">
<div class="post_media">
<div class="flipcard">
<div class="flipcard_front">
<div class="flipcard_content">
<div class="poster">
<img src="<?php echo $imgsrc; $imgsrc = ''; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
<div class="description">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div class="tag"><?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'categoria', '', ', ', ''); ?></div>
<div class="sinopse"><?php if($values = get_post_custom_values("_sinopse")) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?></div>
<span class="description_post">
<ul class="datasheet_post">
<li>
<span class="datasheet_post_elenco">Elenco:</span>
<?php if(get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'personalidade', '', ', ', '')) { ?>
<span>
<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'personalidade', '', ', ', ''); ?>
</span>
<?php } ?>
</li>
<li>
<span class="datasheet_post_criador">Criador:</span>
<?php if(get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'criador', '', ', ', '')) { ?>
<span>
<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'criador', '', ', ', ''); ?>
</span>
<?php } ?>
</li>
<li>
<span class="datasheet_post_genero">Gênero:</span>
<?php if(get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'genero', '', ', ', '')) { ?>
<span>
<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'genero', '', ', ', ''); ?>
</span>
<?php } ?>
</li>
<li>
<span class="datasheet_post_duracao"">Duração:</span>
<?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_runtime')) { ?>
<span>
<?php echo $values[0]; ?>
</span>
<?php } ?>
<span class="date_publication">Publicado em <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span>
</li>
</ul>
</span>
<span class="imdb_post_cont">
<div class="imdb_post_data">
<a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/<?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_imdb_id')) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?>" target="_blank">
<div class="imdb_post_float">
<span class="imdb_post_background"><?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_imdb_points')) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?></span> </div>
</a>
<div class="imdb_post_rating">
<div class="imdb_post_rating_sub">
<span class="imdb_post_rating_p" style="width: <?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_imdb_percentage')) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?>;">
</span>
</div>
<span class="imdb_post_dp">
<a class="imdb_post_imdb_a" href="https://www.imdb.com/title/<?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_imdb_id')) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">IMDB:</a>
<b class="imdb_post_imdb_b"><?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_imdb_points')) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?>/10</b>
<b class="imdb_post_imdb_b"><?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_imdb_votes')) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?></b>
<b class="imdb_post_imdb_b">votos</b>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="parental_rating_description">
<div class="tooltipped tooltipped-nw content_parental content_parental_rating-<?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_classification')) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?>" aria-label="<?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_description')) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?>"><?php if($values= get_post_custom_values( '_classification')) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?></div>
</div>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="post_footer">
<a class="update tooltipped tooltipped-s" aria-label="Atualizado em <?php the_modified_date ('d \d\e F \d\e Y'); ?>">Atualizado em <?php the_modified_date ('d \d\e F \d\e Y'); ?></a>
<a class="download" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Mais Informações</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php $activar_ads = get_option('activar-slider-footer'); if ($activar_ads == "true") { ?>
<?php $random = rand(1,6); if ($ads2 == 3) : ?>
<?php $ads = get_option('slider-footer'); if (!empty($ads)) echo stripslashes(get_option('slider-footer')); ?>
<?php endif; $ads2++; ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<div class="no_principal">
<?php _e('No content available', 'mundothemes'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php pagination(); ?>
</ol>
```

Minha função de paginação:

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) { 
    $pagn = ($range * 2)+1;
    global $paged; if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
    if($pages == '') {
        global $wp_query; $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; 
        if(!$pages){ $pages = 1; } 
    }
    if(1 != $pages) { 
        echo "<div class='paginado'><ul>";

        if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $pagn < $pages) 
            echo "<li><a class=previouspostslink' rel='nofollow' href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>".__( 'First', 'mundothemes' )."</a></li>"; 
        if($paged > 1 && $pagn < $pages) 
            echo "";
        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++){ 
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $pagn )) { 
                echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class='dd'><a class='current'>".$i."</a></li>":"<li><a rel='nofollow' class='page larger' href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."'>".$i."</a></li>";
            } 
        } 
        if ($paged < $pages && $pagn < $pages) 

        if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $pagn < $pages) 
            echo "<li><a rel='nofollow' class=previouspostslink' href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>".__( 'Last', 'mundothemes' )."</a></li>";
            echo "</ul></div>"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depois de dois dias procurando informações e métodos para arrumar esse erro, finalmente encontrei uma maneira.

Já estava quase desistindo, resolvi vim aqui em ultimo caso para perguntar, geralmente sempre tem a galera que sabe mais sobre o assunto, no entanto acabei por solucionando "sozinho"...

Primeiramente já vou logo dizendo que eu não sou nenhum programador, sou apenas um curioso que costuma acertar sempre que quero fazer alguma coisa rs, então não faço nem ideia de como explicar as funções, mas sei que comigo funcionou assim.

Loop (acho que e isso) que eu uso para solicitar as postagens que estão nos meus custom post type:

```
<?php $args = array('post_type'=>array('filmes', 'series'),'paged' => $paged,'orderby'=>'date','posts_per_page' => 2); query_posts($args); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Na solicitação acima eu quero mostrar todos os post que estão nos meus custom post type, que são "filmes" e "series", onde esta escrito "'posts_per_page' => 2" e a quantidade de post que vai ser exibido na index, que no meu caso e apenas 2.

Esses são meus dois custom post type:

[image: Custom Post Type]

A função dos custom post type "filmes" e "series":

```
add_action( 'init', 'post_type_movies' );

function post_type_movies() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                => __( 'Filme' ),
    'singular_name'       => __( 'Filmes' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Adicionar Novo' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Adicionar Novo Filme' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Editar Filme' ),
    'new_item'            => __( 'Novo Filme' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'Todos os Filmes' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'Ver Filme' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Pesquisar Filme' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Nenhum filme encontrado' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Nenhum filme na lixeira' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Filmes' ),
  );

  $supports = array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments');

  $slug = get_theme_mod( 'movies_permalink' );
  $slug = ( empty( $slug ) ) ? 'filmes' : $slug;

  $args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'public'              => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    //'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => $slug ,'with_front' => false),
    'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => $slug ),
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'menu_position'       => 4,
    'supports'            => $supports,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-editor-video',
  );
  $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
  $posts = $wp_query->posts;

  register_post_type( 'filmes', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'post_type_series' );

function post_type_series() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                => __( 'Série' ),
    'singular_name'       => __( 'Séries' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Adicionar Novo' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Adicionar Nova Série' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Editar Série' ),
    'new_item'            => __( 'Nova Série' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'Todas as Séries' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'Ver Série' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Pesquisar Série' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Nenhuma série encontrado' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Nenhuma série na lixeira' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Séries' ),
  );

  $supports = array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments');

  $slug = get_theme_mod( 'series_permalink' );
  $slug = ( empty( $slug ) ) ? 'series' : $slug;

  $args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'public'              => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    //'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => $slug ,'with_front' => false),
    'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => $slug ),
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'menu_position'       => 4,
    'supports'            => $supports,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-editor-video',
  );
  $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
  $posts = $wp_query->posts;

  register_post_type( 'series', $args );

}
```

Aqui e um filtro que eu não sei ao certo o que ele faz, mas esta no meu arquivo functions.php, esta com algumas observações que eu coloquei para meu entendimento:

```
add_filter( 'request' , 'pagination_request_filter' );

function pagination_request_filter( $query ) {
    // https://wpquestions.com/Trouble_with_custom_post_type_pagination/937
    // https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
    if ( empty( $query['preview'] ) && empty( $query['feed'] ) ) {
        $my_post_type = $query['post_type'];
        if ( empty( $my_post_type ) ) {
            //$query['post_type'] = 'any';
            $query['post_type'] = array( 'filmes', 'series');
            //< ?php $args = array('post_type'=>array('filmes', 'series'),'paged' => $paged,'orderby'=>'date','posts_per_page' => 2); query_posts($args); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ? >
            //< ?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged'):1; query_posts(array('post_type' =>array('filmes', 'series'), 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby'=>'date','posts_per_page' => 2)); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ? >
            // Os dois codigos funcionam, não se esquecer de deixar em: 1 post nas Configurações de leitura
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Eu testei com o plugin wp-pagenavi e funcionou, mas se não quiser usar plugin nenhum basta adicionar a função abaixo no seu functions.php:

```
function post_pagination($pages = '', $range = 4) {  
    $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

    global $paged;
    if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

    if($pages == '')
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$pages)
        {
            $pages = 1;
        }
    }   

    if(1 != $pages)
    {
         //echo "<div class='paginacao'><span class='especial'>P&aacute;ginas</span>";
        echo "<div class='paginacao'>";
        if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."' class='current'>&laquo;</a>";
        if($paged > 6 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>1</a> <span class='current'>...</span>";

        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
        {
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
            {
                echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
            }
        }

        if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<span class='current'>...</span> <a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>$pages</a>";
        if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."' class='current'>&raquo;</a>"; 
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Adicione no final da index depois de "endif;", no meu esta depois do endif:

```
<?php post_pagination();?>
```

Até agora não achei nenhum problema, pelo menos comigo esta funcionando liso, se alguém tiver alguma sugestão de como melhorar a função ou algum método melhor, basta comentar.